# Tried to run a ECS task having a app and database, got insufficient memory error, but when I ssh in the EC2 I could start the container with command

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a ECS task that contains a NodeJS app container and a MySQL database container(I know this is not the best practice, but this app has less than 20 concurrent user so RDS is overkill for me) running in a `T2.micro` EC2 instance. When I deployed the task it was not running in the EC2 instance, and the task log says

`"was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching (container-instance 90d4ba...) has insufficient memory available"`

Initially, I thought `T2.micro` instance does not have sufficient memory to run the containers. However, when I ssh into the ec2 instance and manually start my app's container and a MySQL container using `docker run`, they worked just fine. So, I am not sure what exactly is the problem. ECS task log says not enough memory to start the task containing the two containers, but I was able to manually start them when sshing into the instance.

What I have tried:

Running the task with the two containers=>I got insufficient memory error

Removing the MySQL container from the task definition=>The web app container started successfully under ECS

Removing the web app container from the task definition=>I still got insufficient memory error

Manually ssh into the ec2 instance and started the two containers=>They both started successfully